# How to free the JNI env pointer?

Tags: c++, java-native-interface

I have a typical C++ code that launches JNI:

```
JNIEnv* env = NULL;
...
ProcAdd = ( JNI_JVMPROC ) GetProcAddress( hinstLib, "JNI_CreateJavaVM" );
jint createResult = ( ProcAdd ) ( &m_jvm, ( void** ) & env, &vm_args );
```

This works fine. However I am not freeing up env anywhere in my code. I was wondering if I need to free it? And if yes, how?

I ran PurifyPlus on my code and it gives me leak at following line in above code:

```
jint createResult = ( ProcAdd ) ( &m_jvm, ( void** ) & env, &vm_args );
```

The warning given by PurifyPlus is:

[W] MLK: Memory leak of 25941 bytes from 120 blocks allocated in JVM_FindSignal [JVM.DLL]

Answer (score 0):

When you are done with the Java Virtual Machine, you will need to destroy the JVM instance:

```
(*jvm)->DestroyJavaVM(jvm);
```

The `JNIEnv` reference is managed by the JVM, so you don't need to explicitly free it.

Comment: I am destroying the JVM instance. So is it safe to say that the PurifyPlus is giving a false warning? Is there any official document/page which talks about this? I couldn't find one.

Comment: I'm going off the examples in http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/invoke.html#28719. It's entirely possible that there is a memory leak in the JVM itself.